# How do I force a scan of the SD card in Windows 10 mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sd-card

I have windows 10 mobile, and today I find the applications I have stored on my SD card are inaccessible (they don't start, and the icons are blank on the home screen). However data is still accessible on the SD card. I can see my photos for example.  I think it might me a good idea to scan the SD card, like Windows 10 sometimes asks you do to (equivalent of a chkdsk I suppose).

How can I force Windows 10 mobile to do this, instead of just waiting to be asked?

Comment: If you have a PC with a card reader, you could scan it there. I don't think there's a way to manually trigger the "scan and fix" dialog, though it might appear after rebooting the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can't. If you remove SD cart once, your all apps will become inaccessible and garbage. Windows phone cant see apps on sd card. He just uses it as external storage, if you remove it, it starts using it like never used it before. You have to format sd cart to use that unusable old app memory.